# Basic C Program, Babylonian Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, math, integer, double

I'm new to the C language and am trying to do a lab tutorial that we were given at uni.

We've been asked to do the following:

Task 1.
The Babylonian algorithm to compute the square root of a number n is as follows:
1. Make a guess at the answer (you can pick n/2 as your initial guess).

1. Compute r = n / guess
2. Set guess = (guess +r) / 2
3. Go back to step 2 for as many iterations as necessary. The more that steps 2 and 3 are
   repeated, the closer guess will become to the square root of n.

Write a program that inputs an integer for n, iterates through the Babylonian algorithm
five times, and outputs the answer as a double to two decimal places. Your answer will
be most accurate for small values of n.

Here is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int n;

main(void){
    printf("Enter a value for n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    double guess = n / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        double r = n / guess;
        double guess = (guess + r) / 2;
    }
    printf("%d",guess);
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? It spits out ridiculous results; for example if I input "4" as n, the answer should be around "2", but it gives different huge results each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong here.

First, you have scoped a second instance of `guess` inside the loop.  Take away the `double` declaration on that line.  So it should become:

```
guess = (guess + r) / 2;
```

Second, because `guess` is a `double` you need to use `%f` instead of `%d` in the `printf` call.

```
printf( "%f", guess );
```

---

Once you get it working, consider running the algorithm until a certain accuracy is achieved.

```
const double epsilon = 0.0001;
double guess = (double)n / 2.0;
double r = 0.0;
while( fabs(guess * guess - (double)n) > epsilon )
{
    r = (double)n / guess;
    guess = (guess + r) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, both answers were on the money; how do I get it to print to 2 decimal places though?

Comment: Format specifier `"%.2f"`.  Arguable whether you need `"%.2lf"`.  I think floats are implicitly converted to double in variable argument lists.

Comment: `"%lf"` is identical to `"%f"`, the `l` modifier only affects integer types. `float` is converted to `double` for variadic functions so `"%f"` should suffice. On systems that support `long double`, the `"%Lf"` format specifier should be used (n.b. uppercase `L`).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be:

```
guess = guess / 2.0;
```

This would "force" a floating-point operation.

And the variable `guess` is already in the scope. You can´t redeclare it (as you did inside the loop). You can only set it a new value.

And you also need to change the `printf` to :

```
printf("%f",guess);
```

Check this link for more info about the printf formatters:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 2):

The Babylonian Algorithm seems incorrect to me, it should be like this,

```
   int i;
   float n,guess=1;

   printf("\nEnter the Number: ");
   scanf("%f",&n);
   for(i=0;i<PRECISION;i++)
   {
       guess=(guess+n/guess)/2;
   }
   printf("\nThe Square root of %f is %f",n,guess);
```

There are other possible errors also in your program,

There might be the problem of integer division,

The line `double guess = n / 2;`

should be `double guess = (double) n / 2;`

Also the `printf()` should be `printf("%lf",guess);`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this answer addresses undesirable behaviour for input less than two, because of the division by zero: `double r = n / guess;`. There should probably be a check to ensure `n > 0` before entering that loop, too.